# How to run a command on the tick of timer only once if condition is met

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am trying to make this program that uses a Windows Form Timer that shows a message box only if the conditions are met which are `if (test != null && done == false)` after these conditions are met then a messagebox will show up with the Message Of the Day. Then the boolean value of done will be set to false, which is suppose to stop the messagebox from running again. However, the messagebox keeps showing up. Here is my code..

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        String test = null;
        bool done = false;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test = "Good to see you";
            if (test != null && done == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(test);

            }
            done = true;
        }
    }
```

basically I only want to show the message box ONCE then stop, I thought boolean would be the best way to do this. Is there any other way? Please have mercy I am just starting.

Comment: Does your Timer need to continue to Tick? If not, then you could just set its Enabled property to false so that it stops on the condition. Or if you require to continue ticking, but only do something first time through, then I'd use a boolean and set it to true once it's done, as you've coded it above.

Comment: Windows.Forms.TImers used to have a lot of problems with bugs and easy to misuse patterns. I'm sure they have been fixed to some degree in the last few releases, but just be careful.

Comment: You also don't need that null check in there. You're setting the string prior to the check. And you should set done to true inside the if construct. Bear in mind that your timer is still ticking after you display the message box, so you need to set done to true in the if construct PRIOR to displaying the MessageBox. Always change state before doing anything with your UI. And change `done == false` to `!done`.

Comment: if it is just once, why bother about Timer? why can't Form_Load event?

Comment: @techspider because I want it to use timer to check current time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `done=true;` to BEFORE you show the MessageBox.